# Гауссово распределение с ограничениями

Tags: python

Я написал следующий код:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as m

data = np.random.normal(0, 2, 10000000)
data1 = np.random.normal(0, 15, 10000000)
new_data = []
new_data1 = []
for i in range(len(data)):
  if abs(data1[i]) < m.sqrt(2000 * m.exp(-data[i]**2):
    new_data.append(data[i])  
    new_data1.append(data1[i])
```

Мне нужно, чтобы data1[i] было получено из гауссовского распределения и при этом его модуль был меньше чем sqrt(2000 * m.exp(-data[i] * data[i])).

Вопрос таков:
есть ли функция, которая возвращает случайное число из гауссовского распределения(с заданным средним и стандартным отклонением), но имеет устанавливаемые ограничения по возвращающему значению?

Comment: берешь каждое число и сравниваешь

Comment: Удобно использовать списковое сокращение для этого. Ну или можно фильтрацию.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Непонятно - вам нужно получать значения только из "крыльев" гауссова распределения, или пронормировать всё распределение?